# Jquery changing value of text with select LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one drop down box with UL & LI like below:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="rmenu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#" data-value="photo">photo</a></li>
<li><a href="#"data-value="video">video</a></li>
<li><a href="#"data-value="audio">audio</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
```

I also have one hidden field as show above, now I want to change value and also name of hidden field based on value select in LI.

I write `jquery` code as below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#rmenu").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this).parent();
    $("#search_param").val($this.data("value"));
    $("#search_param").name($this.data("value"));
});
</script>
```

But it is not working and not changing even value of name, I have tried all options but no luck.

Comment: why `var $this = $(this).parent();` if click is on and the data- is an a attribute?

Comment: 1) `var $this = $(this).parent();` bad name for a var. Choose a different one, like `parentVal`
2) what's the parent element of `#rmenu`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method `name()` in jQuery. For changing name attribute use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method instead.

```
$("#search_param").attr('name',$this.data("value"));
```

Also there is no need to get parent element, since data attribute set to `a` tag not to `li`.

```
var $this = $(this);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="rmenu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#" data-value="photo">photo</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="video">video</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="audio">audio</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $("#rmenu").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#search_param").val($this.data("value"));
    $("#search_param").attr('name', $this.data("value"));
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have parent(`li`) in your $this, but you have data in `a` tag, also, you can change name with `.attr('name',val)`

```js
$("#rmenu").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#search_param").val($this.data("value"));
    $("#search_param").attr('name',$this.data("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="rmenu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#" data-value="photo">photo</a></li>
<li><a href="#"data-value="video">video</a></li>
<li><a href="#"data-value="audio">audio</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your way will work

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="rmenu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-value="photo">photo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"data-value="video">video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"data-value="audio">audio</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#rmenu > li > a').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $('#search_param').attr('name', val);
        $('#search_param').val(val);
    });
});
</script>
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
$("#rmenu").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#search_param").attr("name",$(this).data("value"))
    $("#search_param").attr("value",$(this).data("value"))
});
</script>
```

Comment: would this not work `$("#search_param").val($this.data("value"));`?

Comment: yup, sure. @guradio